# How to disable particular mat-checkbox in angular14

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular14

I have used angular material in my application.Trying to disable the particular mat checkbox.I have tried but not working properly. It is disbaling all the checkbox.But i want to disable only Car and Motor checkboxes. How to do it? If anyone konws please help to find the solution.

mautocomponent.html:

```
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let data of filteredData | async"
    [value]="data"
    [disabled]="isDisable(data)"
  >
    <div (click)="optionClicked($event, data)">
      <mat-checkbox
        [checked]="data.selected"
        (change)="toggleSelection(data)"
        (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
        [disabled]="isDisable(data)"
      >
        {{ data.item }}
      </mat-checkbox>
    </div>
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

mautocomponent.ts:

```
      isDisable(obj:any){
    //Only disable Car and Motor
    var index = this.rawData.indexOf(obj);
    console.log(index)
    if (index == -1) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }

  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6bvdt7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fmauto%2Fmauto.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close. Why don't you just use the `obj` that you are passing to your `isDisable()` function.

```
isDisable(obj: any){
    console.log(obj)
    if (obj.item === 'Car' || obj.item === 'Motor') {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }

}
```

[SB demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pxi68t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fmauto%2Fmauto.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fmauto%2Fmauto.component.html)

OP asked about passing disable list from parent component (app.component.ts). One of the ways to do it would be, passing the list of disable items from parent to chiild.

```
app.component.ts:
optionsToHide = ['Car', 'Motor'];

app.component.html:
<app-mauto
  ...
  [optionsToHide]="optionsToHide"
  ...
>

mauto.component.ts:

isDisable(obj: any){

  if (this.optionsToHide.findIndex(item => item === obj.item) > -1) 
  {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can i do this from app.component.ts?  I mean Can i pass the two values from app.component .ts to mauto.component.ts

Comment: Yes you can, but I don't have full context how you are deciding on hiding "Car" and "Motor". I have updated the SB to show you an example how you can pass it from app.component.ts

Comment: Please answer this question. I am trying to update the selectOptions value inside post call method but it not working. Why?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mwk6lp?file=src%2Fapp%2F%C3%A4ssets%2Fdata.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mwk6lp?file=src%2Fapp%2F%C3%A4ssets%2Fdata.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Please help to find the solutions. Thanks

Comment: Check the Network call, that API is throwing 403.
`403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.`

Comment: How to check in stackblitz?

Comment: Open Dev Tools in Chrome > Click on Network Tab > make a small change in SB to make it re-run the code > Check the api call for  https://angular-ivy-mwk6lp.stackblitz.io/assets/data.json (it will be in red with status code 403)

Comment: I am asking how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Now i am getting status 200 error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gygjww?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: But get method is working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-local-json-file?file=src%2Fapp%2Fread-json-file-using-httpclient%2Fread-json-file-using-httpclient.component.ts

Comment: How to find out that issue?

Comment: Post another question in SO, as this is not in the scope of your original question.

Comment: New SO 73141228

Comment: I think you can answer for that question